# WPF ListView Button Inherit Font Color

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to make an "invisible" button in a listview column. How can I get a button to inherit the font color from the ListViewItem?

```
<ListView x:Name="lvHistory" ItemsSource="{Binding history}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2" util:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True" SizeChanged="lvHistory_SizeChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="cell_click" Tag="{Binding Serial}" Foreground="{INHERITSOMETHING}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will bind the button's foreground to the same as the ListViewItem

```
Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
```

Comment: Very nice. I have 8 minutes to accept. What resource do you use to figure this out? I can never seem to find the necessary info for this type of stuff on `msdn`.

Comment: I've been developing WPF for about 3 years so it's all reflex now, honestly. for bindings, especially the more knarly ones like FindAncestor and TemplateBindings, this may help! http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/WpfBinding.pdf

Comment: For a more proper coverage of bindings I really recommend Mcdonald's book (http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-4-5-Presentation-Foundation/dp/1430243651/ref=dp_ob_title_bk)